# PowerBi API to get elementbyid for selenium cursor

Tags: sql, database, selenium-chromedriver, powerbi

I have a monitoring app that runs on PowerBI that sources data from a SQL database,
I have added an automation layer with selenium that currently works on the xpath of a specific checkbox and continues as a loop.
Is there a way I can get the checkbox `elementbyid` through an `powerbi api`?
thanks!